# How to submit Two binary(iPhone and iPad) files for same project in App Store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, itunes, submission

I have created Map application for iPhone and I developed same Map application on iPad too by my client requirement. Now I have same Map app project but two .ipa files one for iPhone and another for iPad.

I have already put iPhone version on iTune and it showing status "waiting for review"

1>Now I want to put my iPad version app on iTune with the same project name. How this can be achieve?

2>What Setting should I do in plist file and with xib files?

If there is universal app iPhone/iPad then in app store we can see both iphone and iPad app having same project name...So in my case what steps should I follow. Plz suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't upload two binary versions of the same app under the same name.

You either have to make a universal app (meaning iPhone/iPad app in one app) or submit under another name.

Start reading this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Comment: Yes, but it may be confusing to customers. If you are going to change the name, you should add 'for iPad' to the end of it.

Comment: a solution might be to name your IPad application like this : <the iPhone App name> HD

Comment: Ok...is there any need to change Bundle Identifire in plist file for iPad?

Comment: Yes you should, since you can't upload two different apps with the same bundle ID.

Comment: How can I get different bundle ID. Can I manually change the name of bundle ID?

Comment: Yep got it...It should be "com.abc.app-hd" for iPad. Is it right? As for iPhone I have used "com.abc.app"

Comment: Hey friends my both iPhone & iPad version Map app are live now in Australian continent......Thanks for the answers and followup comments

Answer (score 2):

You can submit multiple apps from the same Xcode Project by using multiple Targets, and editing the Bundle ID suffix of each Target so that each Target has a unique Bundle ID.  You might also want to change the Product name for each Target in the Build settings so that your apps will have different bundle file names.

Note that, unless the iPad version is different enough (uses iPad only APIs for instance) from the iPhone version, it has been reported that Apple might reject a nearly identical iPhone/iPad pair of apps and request that you submit a single Universal build instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted your iPhone and iPad project to be in the same app, you should have built it that way.

However, if you did specifically want a separate iPhone and iPad app, then you should make the difference clear in the names of each app.

There are many companies who have both iPhone and iPad apps on the appstore. Generally, the iPhone app is just called '*appName*' and the iPad version is usually called '*appName for iPad*'.

Examples of this are:-

- *Skype* and *Skype for iPad*
- *Ebay* and *Ebay for iPad*

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to have the exact same name in iTunes Connect, you will have to make it a universal app.

You can cancel the "waiting for review" and submit your universal binary instead:

> Can I reject a binary that has already been submitted for review? 
>   Yes. You are permitted to reject your binary, to remove it from the
>   Apple review queue, when your app is in one of the following iTunes
>   Connect states:
>
> ```
> Waiting For Review
> In Review
> ```
>
> To reject your binary, simply click the Reject Binary button. After
>   the binary has been rejected, you can then indicate you are ready to
>   submit another binary through Application Loader, by clicking on the
>   Ready to Upload Binary button.
>
> Please note that if you reject a binary that is Waiting For Review or
>   In Review, your review time will be reset and you will start over from
>   the beginning once you submit a new binary.

[iTunes Connect FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/11.0.0.9.1.7.1.1.1.1)

However, if you absolutely need to have two seperate applications, you can create a new app in iTunes Connect and name it for example "[your app] for iPad" or "[your app] HD" or something similar like a lot of apps you see on the store.

Are there any particular reasons you aren't submitting a universal application ?

Comment: Actually I am new for this platform and I was not aware of Universal application. Now its too late to develop Universal app as my client will get angry....well thanks for the suggestions...

Comment: Can you tell me how to get another bundle ID for my iPad app? I have used one for iPhone...

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if it was a universal app.

In itunes Connect you cant create/re-use apps-name,sku number,bundle-identifier. You could submit a universal app as update.

If you still want multiple apps, Then you will have to create multiple apps in itunes connect with different name, sku number and bundle-id,

But note one thing **the name of the application installed in the device is what you give on xcode, not the one in itunes connect**. So I guess you could only give that much similarity.

PS if create a app with details{apps-name,sku number,bundle-identifier} and you delete without publishing also, you cant reuse these again.

So tell client the best(may be only possible) solution is Universal app.

Comment: I did not understood your point...My xcode project file name is "Showroom Locator" and I want name as "xxx Showroom Locator" on iTune and Users device. If user install my app on iPhone what will be the name on his device????

Comment: set a differnent name on itunes connect, and keep the same appname for the target in xcode. So user will see the same name in iPhone and iPad, but in effect its differnt app.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same application for both iphone and ipad, for iphone app name will be  - [appliction name],  for ipad it should be - [application name ] HD