# Two different apps in apple app store with same name?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app I want to launch for iphone and for ipad. The ipad version will be used by businesses to input content. The iphone app will be used by their customers on the go to just access the data.

The iphone app is customer oriented, while the ipad app is business oriented. I would like them to have the same name.

Since the first app will only be available on iphone and the second on ipads, I was wondering whether it's possible for them to have the same name.

Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate question. Answer is no you can't detail you can found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315944/how-to-submit-two-binaryiphone-and-ipad-files-for-same-project-in-app-store

Comment: What if I am a customer and I want to download your app on an iPad? Which version should I see?

Answer (score 26):

Two iOS apps currently can not have the same App store name (as entered in iTunes Connect), nor the same bundle ID suffix.  They can, however, have the same name under the icon (the Bundle Display Name as entered in the app's plist).  And two App store names can differ by as little as one character, punctuation mark or space.  Or one can add a suffix, such as "for iPad" (check Apple's rules on use of the latter).

Comment: There may also be some grandfathered apps that were approved before the rule against identical app names was enforced.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an app with the same name if you choose the primary language as English UK and not the English US, for example.

Comment: what would this mean though?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the app name shouldn't matter unless it's copyrighted by someone else which I doubt.

Since the apps would also be separate, when searching for it on an iPhone, only the iPhone version will show, and vice verca.  The only issue you may have is people searching for it on iTunes itself, which may cause in issue with the same names.  You could also put on the end of the app name iPhone or iPad respectively.  It should still look professional with the added names on the end, and will help out users searching for said app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm getting "The App Name you entered has already been used."

Answer (score 0):

You should make a universal app version of your app. That way it will be on both iPhone and iPad stores.

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. On the ipad users will be stores using the app in an ipad kiosk. On iPhone, customers will use it to scan a card on the ipad. So it's a totally different use of the app depending on the device.

Comment: Then they have to have different names.