# Publish new app with existing app name?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, bundle-identifier

I have developed new app in iOS, 
If i publish my app with already existing app name on the appStore, will apple approve my app?

Like if my app name is **ABCD** with bundle id **com.ls.abcd**
and there is already app with the same name(**ABCD**) available on store but with different bundle id.

```
can i use the name **ABCD**? will apple approve my app?
```

Comment: choose a different name instead.

Comment: You can found you answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582568/two-different-apps-in-apple-app-store-with-same-name

and

https://www.quora.com/Can-two-iPhone-apps-have-the-same-name

Comment: @holex Due to some requirement, i want publish a new app with different bundle id but with the same name...

Comment: surely app will approve

Comment: The Bundle ID doesn't matter. The name (as displayed in the App Store) must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppStore display name cannot be identical to any other existing AppStore display name. Apple cannot even review such an app, because when you set one up in iTunes Connect it will show you an error when choosing an existing name.

However, the name that appears below your app icon, after it is installed on a device can be different than the AppStore name and can be identical to other apps' display names. This is called the Bundle Display Name, and can be changed in your app's Info.plist file, under the key called CFBundleDisplayName.