# Different builds for same application in different iTunes stores?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm developing an application for 3 different languages and I want to release in 3 different iTunes store corresponding to the languages.
 There are a lot of audio files corresponding to each language. So if I create one build for all three languages, the size of the application will be very large.
  So if we create three separate builds for 3 different languages, the size of the app will be reduced.
  My question is - Is there an option to upload different builds for different stores for same application? If not what are the other approaches to this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. 
You just need to create a different project for each application in `iTunes Connect` with a different name and the each app needs to have a different `Bundle Id`. The app name in the bundle can be the same.

If you don't want to change the name of the app on iTunes Connect. You can for example, have the same name with different descriptions.

- App Name - Description 1
- App Name - Description 2
- App Name - Description 3

**Note**: Just changing one character will count as a different name.

Comment: But the application name should be different right?

Comment: The application name ca be the same. (Just the Bundle Identifier needs to be different).

Comment: But iTunes not allows duplicated names for applications(not the bundle display name). I mean the display name in iTunes.   Please refer this Q in So. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315944/how-to-submit-two-binaryiphone-and-ipad-files-for-same-project-in-app-store

Comment: Yep, you are right, the app name in the iTunes Connect needs to be different. What I was meaning is the app name in the app project (bundle).

Comment: @jjpp Do you have any other questions?

Comment: I didn't received the right answer yet. I need the apps have same name in iTunes. Is it possible?

Comment: Need to reduce the app size -> so i need to upload same app with same name but different builds in iTunes.

Comment: I see, then I recommend you localising the app for each language and for each language you can upload a new bundle with a different localised name and description.

Comment: @jjpp Did you succeed or do you have any other questions?